# Unable to validate custom JWT token generated by java libraries

Tags: java, scala, oauth-2.0, jwt

we are trying to generate JWT token using java libraries https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt and https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt. But we are facing the same issue while generating the token from these libraries. The issue is as below:

[image: Token verification error:]

While I am trying to verify generated token via https://jwt.io/, I am getting the above error but if I am verifying token via libraries `verify` method it works fine. Below is my  code for generating the token:

```
    private final val keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA")
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(512)
    private val keyPair =  keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair(
    val rsaPublicKey = keyPair.getPublic.asInstanceOf[RSAPublicKey]
    val rsaPrivateKey = keyPair.getPrivate.asInstanceOf[RSAPrivateKey]

val algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256(rsaPublicKey, rsaPrivateKey)
    val expiry  = Date.from(LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(2).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant)

    val token = JWT.create()
        .withKeyId(KID)
        .withSubject(SUBJECT_KID)
        .withExpiresAt(expiry)
        .withIssuer("http://test.com")
        .sign(algorithm)

println(token)
```

Do you have an idea, what is the problem with this code and how can we solve it?

Comment: just look on the right column on your screenshot, seems you didn't paste your secret or key. How could jwt.io verify a token without knowing the key?

Comment: Hey @jps , generally when keycloak generated the token for me, we just copy and paste token to jwt.io for decode and validate the token for debugging perpective. Then in that case, where we need to add private key?

Comment: @HarmeetSinghTaara On jwt.io under "Verify signature" you should see something [like this](https://imgur.com/tnR7fi1). With the contents of the public & private keys you used to sign the token. BTW: I wouldn't trust jwt.io with production keys. Use this only to check that your dev keys work and you are producing compliant tokens. Never share your production private key